# Google Docs thumbnails do not update, can I force an update?

Tags: google-docs

I am working with Google Docs. I make copies of existing documents using the option **File - Make a copy...**. The document gets copied and I work on the copy and change the copy. When I close it and reopen it the changes I made are applied but in the overview **Docs Home** the old preview stays.

When is this updated?

Is there an option to force an update?

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser cache and cookies or to access Google Docs on private navigation mode?

Comment: Yes, this also happens after cleaning and also in private mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's very simple.
Here's the challenge the way I understand it.
You've changed a document, most notably an image.
The document updated great but the thumbnail still presents the old image.

Here's my way of fixing.

1. Make a copy of the document.  You'll then see a second thumbnail appear but this time with the new image.
2. Delete the original document.
3. Rename the copy.

There you have it.
An updated thumb.

Comment: Why does the thumbnail in Docs Home matter this much? I would have thought the edit and comment histories are more important than copying and deleting the original file for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Found another way to update that doesn't require re-authoring the document. If it's in your quick-access row, right click the old thumbnail, and click "Locate". This forced an update of the thumbnail for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file, then click **`Undo`**, and it will generate a new thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF preview of a link to GDrive in a document is not updating, you can fix it like @Drew by going to the list of documents and reopening the document.