# Google Team Drive Doc in my Slack channel shows an old document title and thumbnail when posting, confusing team members

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, slack, google-shared-drive, thumbnail

How can I force an update on the thumbnail and doc title? Slack doesn't seem to do periodic re-checks since the first time it cached the info. I've tried the command "refresh" the file, but does not work. This is in Team Drive, btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Docs thumbnails do not update, can I force an update?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101643/google-docs-thumbnails-do-not-update-can-i-force-an-update)

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I tried this from RayB, and it helped: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/140932

- went to my test channel
- posted the Google Doc link
- chose "delete file from Slack" from its menu
- reposted the link
- Voilà! it posted with the new title and thumbnail